# Re-cycling the graph architecture

Tags: tensorflow, graph

I'm new to tensorflow so apologies of my question is not relevant. I would like to re-cycle the graph implementation of tensorflow for a different purpose than deep-learning. The idea is to use each node to perform some calculations and output either a number or a dictionary to the dependent nodes that will perform some more calculations and so on. At the end, a summary of all the intermediate results is returned. Does a similar use case exist?

Comment: If I've understood the question correctly, you can use the TF graph for purposes other than deep learning, as explained [here](https://www.pythonprogramming.in/learn-tensorflow-series/basic-tensor-calculations.html). Simply code your calculations, then see the [graph](https://www.pythonprogramming.in/learn-tensorflow-series/creating-and-accessing-computation-graph-in-tensorflow.html). There, each node represents an operation and edges correspond to the [tensors](https://www.pythonprogramming.in/learn-tensorflow-series/creating-and-processing-tensors.html)(simply multi dimensional vectors) that